# How to inject Vite plugin preamble when using `renderToPipeableStream`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stream, vite, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to add SSR to Vite. Since I'm using code splitting with `React.lazy` and `Suspense` I can't use `renderToString` and instead need to use `renderToPipeableStream` to incrementally stream the HTML to the frontend.

The problem is that Vite expects to transform the index.html

```
template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template)
```

However, `renderToPipableStream` does not allow for custom templates, so I can't transform the template and have `renderToPipableStream` emit it incrementally.

And `transformIndexHtml` does not support streams.

If I don't inject the preamble, react throws an error that the preamble is missing.

How can I solve this and use SSR with Vite and Suspense?